# Keeping redux and react-router in sync

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a react (0.14) + redux (3.3) + react-redux (4.4) + react-router (2.0) app with three components: `PostsLists` which is a list of blog post titles, `Post` which shows a blog post and `Blog` which wraps these components:

```
             ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────┐
             │                                              │
             │ ┌─────────────┐┌──────────────────────────┐  │
             │ │             ││                          │  │
             │ │  Post 1     ││ ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┐  │  │
             │ │  Post 2     ││       Post title         │  │
             │ │  Post 3     ││ └ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┘  │  │
             │ │             ││                          │  │
             │ │             ││ ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┐  │  │
             │ │             ││                          │  │
             │ │             ││ │                     │  │  │
             │ │             ││      Post contents       │  │
             │ │             ││ │                     │  │  │
             │ │             ││                          │  │
             │ │             ││ │                     │  │  │
             │ │             ││  ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │  │
             │ │  PostsList  ││          Post            │  │
             │ └─────────────┘└──────────────────────────┘  │
             │                                              │
             │                     Blog                     │
             └──────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So far my redux state is just an array of blog posts:

```
{posts: [{title: 'Post 1', contents: '…'}]}
```

The routes are

```
/posts
/posts/:id
```

At `/posts` only the `PostLists` is shown, while on `/posts/:id` `Post` is also shown (it will be a child of `Blog`). The post list `Link`s to `/posts/:id`.

`Blog` will fetch the blog posts from a HTTP api when it's mounted, so if loading e.g. `/posts/1` `Post` may be mounted before there is a post to show.

My question is about managing the current active post. My initial idea – that I still quite like – is to have a `current_post` field in the state:

```
    {posts: [{title: 'Post 1', contents: '…'}],
     current_post: {title: 'Post 1', contents: '…'}}
```

However, when e.g. loading `/posts/1`, who should be responsible for updating `current_post` (in a way that makes sure that `Post` is reloaded when it changes)? If `Post` is a container and I use `mapStateToProps` to have `current_post`, will it get re-rendered when `current_post` is changed?

The other alternative is to inspect `props.params.id` in `Post` and then find the right post, but this seems a bit dirty. How do people usually structure an app like this?

Answer (score 1):

For an application like this, I would structure the redux store as follows:

```
{posts: [{id: 1, title: 'Post 1', contents: '…'}],
 current_post: {id: 1}}
```

The `PostsList` component would be responsible for keeping `current_post` up-to-date (i.e. when the user clicks on one of the entries, an action would be triggered that reduces the `id` of the newly selected post into the redux store). The `Post` component would read the `id` of the current post, extract the relevant data from the `posts` array and display it. Each time the user changes the current post, all components will be re-rendered, and thus the whole screen will be updated.

Comment: Thanks. But what about when the app starts at `/posts/1`? (I.e. when there is no click.) I guess `PostsList` should read `parameters.id` and set `current_post` when data is received.

Comment: Another scenario: there is a link to `/posts/2` from `/posts/1`, now `PostsList` isn't involved at all and never noticed anything when the location changed, so we're out of sync. I guess one needs to listen to the location and then update the current post in a reducer based on a url change…

Comment: When the app starts at `posts/1`, then the `current_post` needs to be set to 1 as well (my version was a bit simplistic, admittedly). Actually, even `PostsList` should read `current_post` and use it to highlight the selected post. When you have other components in your app (other than `PostsList`) that determine which post gets displayed, then you need to trigger an action to update `current_post` from these as well (e.g. when a user clicks a link).

Comment: The key concept behind this is that the redux state does not necessarily belong to just one component; instead it describes the overall state of your application, and it informs all components at once. Also, all involved components need to make sure that they update the state.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest loading post data based off the route via props.params, then checking for updates using `componentWillReceiveProps`. That will let you compare the current post ID (based on the URL) with the incoming post and decide if anything needs updating.

Put it in whichever component is responsible for firing off data retrieval actions.

You could also store this info in your store(s), but I'm not sure you'd gain much. If you want to be able to manage navigation state in your store I'd recommend https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-router